# how to view pdf files in webbrowser without adobe acrobat plug-in

Tags: vb.net, browser

Im trying to view a pdf file in a webbrowser but im getting an error that says "cannot find adobe acrobat plug-in" im using foxit for my pdf viewer is there another way of viewing my pdf files?

thanks all answers are highly appreciated